# Key Error = client_id -- django

Tags: python, django, synapsepay

I have an api that i am using for a project that I am working on. I am getting a key errror for the client Id that I have to pass in order ot call the api. THe api that i am using is Synapse. If anyone knows what is cuasing the error or how I can fix this key error, it would be a lit of help... Here is the full error.

```
KeyError at /
'client_id_...6YiBl'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'client_id_...YiBl'
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py in __getitem__, line 669
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

here is the code:

```
import os
from synapse_pay_rest import Client

args = {
    'client_id': os.environ['client_id_...YiBl'],
    'client_secret': os.environ['client_secret_...C3IF'],
    'fingerprint': '599378e9a63ec2002d7dd48b',
    'ip_address': '127.0.0.1',
    'development_mode':True,
    'logging':False
}

client = Client(**args)
```

Comment: I've edited out the full secret/ids you had in code. I'd suggest invalidating them in Synapse and issuing new credentials.

Comment: thank you. i realized after that I have my client id and client secret... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like it should be using the keys directly, whereas you're trying to access environment variables.

Basically, don't try to access these values via `os.environ()`, as it will make your application search for an environment variable named `client_id_...YiBl`.

```
from synapse_pay_rest import Client

args = {
    'client_id': 'client_id_...YiBl',
    'client_secret':'client_secret_...C3IF',
    'fingerprint': '599378e9a63ec2002d7dd48b',
    'ip_address': '127.0.0.1',
    'development_mode':True,
    'logging':False
}

client = Client(**args)
```

Comment: @OmarJandali sure thing, what's the question? Feel free to edit it into your original question and let me know.

Comment: I have a problem and i wanted to know if you would know how to fix this problem i am getting with the user command... the following is the message that i am getting. `AttributeError at /setup_profile/
type object 'User' has no attribute 'create'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
type object 'User' has no attribute 'create'
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in createUserSynapse, line 1104` @birryree